# Calculate dot-product using map and lambda in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, map-function

Calculate dot product of two vectors `v` and `w`. My thinking is get the product of first items in vectors, and use accumulate function to add them all together.

```
 (define (dot-product v w)
   (accumulate + 0 (map (lambda(v,w)(* (car v) (car w))) (list v w))))
```

I don't understand why this does not work:

```
 (dot-product (list 1 2) (list 3 4)) //output is 12, not the 11 that I anticipated
```

I think I have big trouble understanding how `map` function works in this case, thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not an answer, but I needed to show some code.

This shows why your original didn't work.

Let's define `v` and `w` so we can use them in examples.

```
> (define v '(1 2))
> (define w '(3 4))
```

Now let's see where your computation begins:

```
> (map (lambda (v,w) (* (car v) (car w))) (list v w))
'(3 9)
```

This is probably not the result you expected. The problems is that `(v,w)` is turned into `(v (unquote w))` by the reader. What you meant was:

```
> (map (lambda (v w) (* v w)) v w)
'(3 8)
```

And if you put that into your original example, you get 12.

Note that `(lambda (v w) (* v w))` is the same as `*`.

```
> (map * v w)
'(3 8)
```

Answer (score 4):

The way you're invoking `map` won't have the desired effect. Giving the list of `(list v w)` means that your function is called twice, once with `v`, once with `w` (no matter how many items each of those lists have).

Instead, do this:

```
(define (dot-product v w)
  (apply + (map * v w)))
```

Here, you are passing two lists to `map`, which means it will call your function (`*` in this case) with two arguments: one for each list given.

Comment: Thank you! sorry that I still confused about one thing: isn't map going to go through each element in the (list v w)? why this function only be called twice?

Comment: @user3366240 `(list v w)` is a list of two elements (the first element is `v`, and the second element is `w`).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. But do you know how that 12 was computed? when the fun called twice the result should be 3.

Comment: `(dot-product '(1 2) '(3 4)) = (apply + map * '(1 2) '(3 4)) = (apply+ (list (* 1 3) (* 2 4)) = (apply + (list 3 8)) = (+ 3 8) = 11`

Comment: Thanks @soegaard, but I am still trying to figure out how my code calculate that wrong answer,  so I can learn not to make that mistake again.  I assume in (lambda(v,w)(* (car v) (car w)), the inputs are 1 and 3, and output is 3, but somehow I get 12.

Comment: @user3366240 See my answer (too much code for a comment)